# LARAVEL - DOMPDF - customize footer for first and other pages

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I have two footers like this:

**1. Footer A**

```
<footer class="footer first">footer for 1st page</footer>
```

**2. Footer B**

```
<footer class="footer second">footer for 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ...n page</footer>
```

And full code like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page { margin: 10px 0px; size: A4 }
            .footer { position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 0px; right: 0px; background-color: lightblue; height: 50px; }
            .footer.first {  }
            .footer.second {  }
            .page { padding: 15px; page-break-after: always; }
            .page:last-child { page-break-after: never; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <footer class="footer first">footer for 1st page</footer>
        <footer class="footer second">footer for 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ...n pages</footer>
        <main>
            <div class="page">page1</div>
            <div class="page">page2</div>
            <div class="page">page3</div>
            <div class="page">page4</div>
            <div class="page">page...n</div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

But this is show the same footer for every page (**Footer B**), is it possible to customize only first page is different with other pages ?

The first page show **Footer A** and the other show **Footer B**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Do you want to display the two different footers on different pages? If so, the answer is simple: Just create two different HTML files and fill them both with the different sets of information or you could use the  `request()->is('/(your required HTML page)')` method in the place for the info as some kind of dynamic filling. So your code will look like this

```
<footer class="footer {{ request()->is('/first') ? 'first' : '' }}">{{ request()->is('/firstpage') ? 'The text' : '' }}</footer>
```

for the second footer

```
<footer class="footer {{ request()->is('/second') ? 'second' : '' }}">{{ request()->is('/firstpage') ? 'The text' : '' }}</footer>
```

You should check out the laravel docs link for more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests